# When launching django-app from herroku, it says "application error", but the logs doesn't show any error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, github, heroku

I am working at a django app (noob) in PyCharm and back it up on GitHub. I want to run the app from heroku and I created an workspace and deployed the app from the Git link. In logs it says that the app is launching, but when I am trying to acces the page, it says "application error! An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details." 
This is the log:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       94 static files copied to '/tmp/build_92826bd11c22ebfaffc04da632fb123d/USR/static'.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 49.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v12
       https://backend-educational.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Any idea about what am I missing?

Comment: There must be additional logs being written that tell you what the issue is. What is the output of [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs)?

Comment: That's the build log from when you pushed your code and Heroku built your app. Runtime logs are accessible by `heroku logs`, as solarissmoke says.

Comment: But I can't find anywhere the runtime logs. (I am not using heroku from command line)

Comment: Check your logs on your activity tab on the heroku page, and see what it says.